# unknow system variable: "new.id" is not recognized

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

Let's say 6,7,8 are all taken, and l tried to insert data with id = 6. The purpose of the trigger is to find the next available number. However, MySQL does not recognize new.id
Or, can l alter auto_increment's value? 
Why am l doing this? Because in OracleDB, the sequence generator will increment(and eventually find that available number) whereas MySQL's sequence generator won't increment if a duplicate primary key is generated somehow.

tried to replace "new.id = @valid" with "alter table wooster_brush_employee auto_increment = @valid" in trigger, but it did not work. 

`create table wooster_brush_employee(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    first_name varchar(15),
    last_name varchar(20),
    username varchar(10),
    password varchar(15),
    email varchar(30)
);
delimiter //
create trigger validate_id before insert on wooster_brush_employee
    for each row
    set @old = last_insert_id();
    set @valid = last_insert_id();
    call wooster_brush_employee_id_validator(@old, @valid);
    set NEW.id = @valid;
    end;
delimiter;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your whole approach here is off kilter, and you don't even need to use this trigger.  The point of an auto increment column, in either MySQL or Oracle, is that the database handles the problem of finding the next available number in the sequence.  While the auto increment contract does not guarantee that the next value found will be *greater* than every value already in the column, it does guarantee that the next value will be *unique*.

So, if you want to make use of MySQL's auto increment functionality, then next time you insert, simply omit `id` from the column list:

```
INSERT INTO wooster_brush_employee (first_name, last_name, username, password, email)
VALUES
    ('Jon', 'Skeet', 'jonskeet', '*****", 'jon.skeet@google.com');
```

Since `id` was omitted, MySQL will automatically generate the next value in the sequence behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi, l appreciate your response. But l did encounter problem in development that auto_increment is at 1, and 2 is taken, so auto_increment stuck at 1 because 2 is already taken. That is why l am trying to call SP with trigger in case something like that happens. Do you know how to set the new id to the next valid value before insert?

Comment: Your comment/situation does not really change my answer.  If you need such a sequence, then you should _not_ be relying on the auto increment column.  Instead, use something like `ROW_NUMBER`.